# How can I access certificates installed in a apple OS X

Tags: java, macos, x509certificate, digital-certificate

As in Windows, that we have the really old Capicom, that interfaces the CryptoAPI equivalent for us, is there something that helps getting a certificate in a apple system?

If not, is there some way to access them? By bouncy Castle, Itext, java native...

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for OSX's keychain. Java has an API which interacts with it using the [`KeyStore`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html). The method of interest to you is probably `getCertificate`.

Answer (score 7):

You can access the KeyChain with the Java KeyStore API as said by @vcsjones. This is some code sample:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("KeychainStore");
ks.load(null);
Enumeration<String> e = ks.aliases();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = e.nextElement();
    if (ks.isCertificateEntry(alias)) {
        System.out.printf("%s (certificate)\n", alias);
    } else if (ks.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
        System.out.printf("%s (key)\n", alias);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%s (???)\n", alias);
    }
}
```